# what is topicId or userId in pem file

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am following "https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Generating+a+MDM+APNS+Certificate" to configure the IOS in emm. 
Currently I blocked in "step 5 openssl x509 -in MDM_Certificate.pem -text -noout". In the output of this command, what is userid or topicId?
The output looks like below:

> Certificate:
>       Data:
>           Version: 3 (0x2)
>           Serial Number: 1447901517943550403 (0x1417fac25ec631c3)
>       Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>           Issuer: C=US, O=Apple Inc., OU=Apple Certification Authority, CN=Apple Application Integration Certification Authority
>           Validity
>               Not Before: Dec 10 05:43:53 2014 GMT
>               Not After : Dec 10 05:43:53 2015 GMT
>           Subject: UID=com.apple.mgmt.External.7c0b241a-df97-41f4-a538-5149bd4a559d,
>   CN=APSP:7c0b241a-df97-41f4-a538-5149bd4a559d, C=cn
>           Subject Public Key Info:
>               Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>                   Public-Key: (2048 bit)
>                   Modulus:
>                       00:cd:65:71:1c:ba:61:8e:d0:1a:d9:fe:c0:c3:81:
>                       ce:f0:b0:54:65:3c:b1:ca:08:60:f8:ba:92:22:5e:
>                       45:67:09:7f:6a:fc:3d:ca:3b:5d:de:ca:ac:8f:48:
>                       a1:1b:93:06:11:49:0d:39:0e:94:d3:95:f4:1a:7d:
>                       40:f5:1d:f7:97:ab:c1:9c:69:c1:e1:93:2e:8f:6e:
>                       c4:a5:ca:8b:93:b9:ff:22:9d:88:41:fe:b4:67:b0:
>                       6e:9d:14:4e:e6:cb:28:1e:ac:16:33:fc:3a:49:1d:
>                       7d:b8:78:0d:f9:3e:7c:c0:cb:01:e0:39:43:65:74:
>                       f2:ea:64:b2:8b:3d:1e:9a:1e:18:d3:49:4f:f9:2d:
>                       df:71:de:07:f4:b1:04:14:5a:f6:88:a4:43:88:5d:
>                       68:c5:02:5a:7c:37:11:a4:e5:b1:6a:85:2f:01:d6:
>                       e8:af:f6:ae:f7:36:18:a2:a7:62:a9:1b:a3:ce:d0:
>                       e7:48:37:a9:32:c8:f8:94:49:16:f5:dc:c5:1a:82:
>                       b8:06:c1:9b:80:9e:81:e8:0c:ba:eb:2f:ad:93:b0:
>                       2b:ac:48:07:23:d3:8a:12:f6:63:a9:41:cc:e2:e8:
>                       1d:8d:55:79:76:94:2e:98:55:ea:9d:06:0c:fc:cd:
>                       d5:b1:aa:8b:b3:5b:2b:72:c2:79:5d:48:74:33:17:
>                       d1:93
>                   Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
>           X509v3 extensions:
>               X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
>                   8A:07:ED:27:9B:9A:DA:8B:B2:AF:5A:60:98:E5:45:7C:BC:B4:CB:CE
>               X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
>                   CA:FALSE
>               X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
>                   keyid:31:EA:76:A9:23:74:A5:DF:D4:FD:EE:A0:C1:A6:9E:C6:11:0E:11:EC
>
> ```
>         X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
>             Policy: 1.2.840.113635.100.5.1
>               User Notice:
>                 Explicit Text: Reliance on this certificate by any party assumes acceptance of the then applicable standard terms and
> ```
>
> conditions of use, certificate policy and certification practice
>   statements.
>                     CPS: http://www.apple.com/appleca/
>
> ```
>         X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 
>
>             Full Name:
>               URI:http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/aaica.crl
>
>         X509v3 Key Usage: 
>             Digital Signature
>         X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
>             TLS Web Client Authentication
>         1.2.840.113635.100.6.3.2: 
>             ..
> Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>      51:ae:7e:d7:ec:de:bb:54:4e:1e:cd:aa:5a:f2:a7:5e:86:f1:
>      46:b8:72:d0:e9:76:df:78:e8:39:f6:79:13:ab:1c:cf:dd:c4:
>      83:36:14:98:52:75:70:a1:27:b8:1b:e0:d0:16:ac:4d:14:3f:
>      d4:6b:b5:24:34:14:25:fd:23:d2:09:21:66:9d:6f:a6:69:47:
>      14:c5:fe:f8:11:4c:08:fd:1f:06:ee:2a:65:d8:f9:db:a9:88:
>      a9:56:5f:61:b7:27:5b:86:93:36:79:96:ec:dc:59:97:0a:f7:
>      ce:bd:06:a1:45:4c:2b:3a:82:b3:d3:27:5a:b3:da:d0:59:2d:
>      27:76:70:ff:50:66:55:dc:a6:b1:80:96:a2:5e:56:c3:6f:f1:
>      d7:e5:2c:a4:21:a8:db:d6:93:d3:83:21:93:8e:b0:14:6e:9e:
>      24:68:eb:79:9f:59:e0:9c:78:12:5e:2d:b3:6a:ba:3f:6e:71:
>      6b:1c:32:f8:ac:4d:73:d4:08:83:7f:6f:fb:9c:8b:70:1f:4f:
>      91:85:12:aa:d0:55:83:5f:67:d7:d8:ac:50:15:1e:a4:f2:ee:
>      aa:a3:a2:b0:3c:f6:ff:c3:8d:47:5a:34:f2:58:60:7c:12:29:
>      91:e9:87:25:0e:e2:c6:14:c9:d1:84:18:20:b7:fa:a3:b8:93:
>      da:d9:e9:8e
> ```

Answer (score 1):

oh, it is UID=com.apple.mgmt.External.7c0b241a-df97-41f4-a538-5149bd4a559d.